# Expectation of division of random variables

Tags: probability, random-variable, expected-value

Is this true?
E(Xn/Yn) goes to E(Xn)/E(Yn) in probability even if Xn and Yn are not independent?

Comment: It's difficult to find *any* circumstance in which this is true!

Comment: What is the source of this question?

Answer (score 2):

It is not. Take $X_n \sim Bernoulli(p)$ and $Y_n=X_n+1$.

$E(X_n/Y_n)=p/2$

$E(X_n)=p$

$E(Y_n)=p+1$

$p/2\neq p/(p+1)$ in general.